# JMeter - Display thread group name in Log errors and exception

Tags: logging, groovy, jmeter

I have a numerous of tests that Using the same steps.
the problem is that if I run all of them together I got exceptions in error log,
the problem is that I can not differentiate from which thread group the error / exception comes from.
How can I saw or add to the exceptions / error the thread name?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind showing your relevant script?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code in try and catch and log an error including Thread group name, e.g.:

```
try {
   "1".substring(1,100);
}catch(Throwable e) {
   log.error(ctx.getThreadGroup().getName() + ":" + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Comment: Hey @user7294900 I do not understand where to put it? since I can not know on which step it will fail. can you please be more specific where to write it? to add new sampler? shall I put it in all tests or just in the test plan level?

Comment: inside your JSR223 script(s) you should try to catch all exception in all your code, and then write to log an error